# How to load multiple pages in electron like shift

Tags: angularjs, node.js, electron, chromium

I am building a desktop app for the company's internal administration.
And decided to build UI like [shift](https://tryshift.com/) which can browse multiple internal tools like trello, google drives and etc.

I know that I can use `browserView` in the `main process` to load external URL.

1. Is there a chance that I can use the same functionality within the `renderer process` to keep the navigation bar like shift?
2. Also few static files were refused to load in `browserView`. why is it happening?

Comment: It's not really clear what this has to do with Angularjs, or node.js for that matter.  Neither of those technologies would have any impact on anything relating to this question at all.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You have a greater chance of getting a useful answer by including a minimum viable complete example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. To quickly give some pointers, yes in theory you can access some parts of browserView from renderer however keep in mind that the main process really has the responsibility in Electron for managing windows and views, you would generally message between renderer and main, with windowing instructions. You'll need to give a specific error message to assist with the static file error and I suggest creating a separate question for this.